# changing schema in hive from string to double

Tags: hive

I uploaded a csv file to hive using a script but by mistake the default for all columns was string though I wanted it to be double. What is the best way to make a table change all columns to double in hive? Will the data be automatically cast to double?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it for all column

```
// will change column a's name to a1 and type to double
ALTER TABLE test_change CHANGE a a1 DOUBLE;
```

syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE [COLUMN] col_old_name col_new_name column_type [COMMENT col_comment] [FIRST|AFTER column_name]
```

**NOTE:** The column change command will only modify Hive's metadata, and will NOT touch data. Users should make sure the actual data layout conforms with the metadata definition.

For more

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment